# how to use getparam from navigation properly in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im using react navigation v4
I used the navigation.navigate to send params in other page i built,
when I try to do the same in other page I get undefined value.

I want to pass that

```
let VolunteerDest = documentSnapshot.data().delegation;
console.log('testing user delegation: ', VolunteerDest)  // <~~~~~~~~~ its working ~~~~~~~~~~
this.props.navigation.navigate('Volunteer', {userDelegation: VolunteerDest});
```

and on the other page I tried it in compDidMount / Constructor.. none of them working:

```
 const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('userDelegation');
 console.log('testing user delegation:' , id);  // <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  undefined
```

can someone please tell me whats wrong with it?
I read the navigation doc and searched here and google but cant find my mistake.(like I said it worked on different page navigation but here I face that issue)

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to worry about it, you can also get the value in state like this

```
this.state = {
        subCatName: this.props.navigation.state.params.userDelegation
    };
```

Comment: tnx for ur answer, it gives me: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subCatName' of undefined.` maybe problem with stack navigator? but if it brings me to that page i assume it should pass the value aswell

Comment: hey it's my mistake actually you don't need to put subCatName after params you need to call your Keyword like. userDelegation

Answer (score 0):

```
    First Scrren :

     <Button
              title="Go Next"
              //Button Title
              onPress={() =>
                navigate('SecondPage', {
                  JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: this.state.username,
                })
              }/>


Second:

First Use this line

 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

then after  {this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item
            ? this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item
            : 'No Value Passed'}
```